# How do create a global visit counter that echoes an image for every visit?

Tags: php, image

Basically I want to create a global visit counter of a web page, then I want to display an image for every visit. So if 10 people have visited the page, 10 random images from the server will be echoed on that page. When the 11th visitor arrives on the page a new random image will be echoed and so on...

So I need help with two things really -

1. I have a very basic visit counter but it only works in sessions, I need it to work globally?
2. How do I echo images according to the number of visits?

Here is the basic code I have for a visit counter:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
   $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
else
   $_SESSION['views']=1

echo "Page views: ".$_SESSION['views'];
```

I am still a massive beginner at php and any help would be hugely appreciated :)

Thanks guys.

Comment: You can't do this with sessions. Sessions are valid only for the current visitor (session). You can't use sessions for unique counts. You'd need a database or a text file or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

if you chose not to store your data in the database then this code should work well for you, all you have to do is find images from 0 to 9, and create empty text file named counter.txt and place this code in your php file somewhere

```
$file = "counter.txt";
$count = file_get_contents($file);
$fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("ccould not open file");
$content = (int)$count + 1;
fwrite($fh, $content);
fclose($fh);
$counter_array = str_split($content);
foreach($counter_array as $digit){
    echo "<img src='" . $digit . ".gif' />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### SESSIONS are **NOT** for global storage.

They are only alive till the website is open.

> You should use database to store the global variable.

---

Now, coming to the image display part. You can name of images with number specific to no of visits.

> **For example:**
>
> 4.jpg will be the Image that is when to the fourth guy

Next, you can use a simple snippet like this

```
$visitCounter = "?"; //Get the count using a logic
echo "<img src="$visitCounter.jpg" />"; //Use it to create a image path
```

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION is the wrong use for this.

Back in the day, I would read and write to a text file on the server. Not the best method due to flock issues, but it will give you some experience reading and writing a file.